# Property Get Value Based on Condition

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to create a class that returns a path in a `string` based on a `Boolean`.  For instance, I have a property called `ErrorLog`.  If the current environment is development, the string returned for the property is `"C:\LogFiles\AppLogs\ErrorLogs"` and in production, the string returned would be `"D:\LogFiles\AppLogs\ErrorLogs"`

I can determine the environment in a method and return a `boolean` - I just don't know how to return the correct path.  I have been looking at conditional properties, but am not sure this is the best method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
protected String ErrorLog
{
get {return YourMethodThatReturnTrueIfDevelopment() ? "C:\LogFiles\AppLogs\ErrorLogs" : "D:\LogFiles\AppLogs\ErrorLogs";}

set {ErrorLog = value;}
}
```

Define the `Get` method, returning a `Bool` that eval which enviroment is, and then use the [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to return one or another string.

Anyway, this is how to do what you ask; I recommend (after seeing) the Icarus' answer

Comment: Why is ErrorLog a Boolean - shouldn't it be a string?

Answer (score 1):

You should look at Web.config transformations since you are using VS 2010. With this you can set up the path to the log file in the `appSettings` section and have it automatically changed to the appropriate value when you deploy your app to Production.

There's a very complete example [here.](http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2009/10/13/common-web-config-transformations-with-visual-studio-2010.aspx)

Comment: This looks interesting - I'll definetly give it a good read, but I would need this in the creation of referenced classes where there is no web.config - for example a business logic layer.